# Authparams in auth0js

Tags: cordova, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic2, auth0

i need to set additional parameters in auth0 to make the audience url work correctly. In authlock you can simply do this:

```
 var lock = new Auth0Lock('clientID', 'account.auth0.com', {
auth: {
 params: {
  audience: 'url'
  }
 }
});
```

I guess I need to add the code to my auth0config within my authservice but i'm not sure what and how:

```
 const auth0Config = {
 // needed for auth0
 clientID: 'id',

 // needed for auth0cordova
 clientId: 'id',
 domain: 'url',
 callbackURL: location.href,
 packageIdentifier: 'id',

};
```

Who can tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Auth0 ionic 2 quickstart, tried adding audience [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic2-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/services/auth.service.ts#L58) (along with updating scope info):

Reading the source, expected this to work since later on when the cordova library uses auth0.js, it eventually calls [this code](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/blob/master/src/authentication/index.js#L100) and should merge the baseOptions with passed in Options. However, for some reason didn't seem to work.

Instead, I had to force the baseOptions by adding an extra entry here for the audience in the [Cordova library itself](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova/blob/master/src/index.js#L34) eg.

```
function CordovaAuth(options) {
  this.clientId = options.clientId;
  this.domain = options.domain;
  this.redirectUri = options.packageIdentifier + '://' + options.domain + '/cordova/' + options.packageIdentifier + '/callback';
  this.client = new auth0.Authentication({
    clientID: this.clientId,
    domain: this.domain,
    // just hard coded here for time being - need a check to see if present first..
    audience: options.audience, 
    _telemetryInfo: telemetry
  });
}
```

And then pass the audience in [here instead](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic2-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/services/auth.service.ts#L12) - this is the same section of code you put in your question. Doing the above does work, and produces a JWT Access token with supplied scopes, but unclear why simply adding audience to options did not work instead...

Interesting the API seems to indicate that it [expects audience](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova/blob/master/src/index.js#L58) and this line suggests the audience [would be propogated](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova/blob/master/src/index.js#L82) and used to build the `authorizeUrl` [here](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova/blob/master/src/index.js#L89).

Have left an open issue with the Auth0 quickstarts team to clarify. But the above solution will allow you to work with a JWT Access token in meantime. You can either fork [the repo](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova) and control it that way, or just for testing go ahead and edit [the source](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova/blob/master/src/index.js#L34) inside your `node_modules` folder to check it works for you.

Shall post an update on this answer once I hear back from the Auth0 quickstarts team regarding the "official" solution to this.

Comment: I also asked on the auth0 forum and got an answer, but me being not so lucky, it did not work.
Post is here: https://community.auth0.com/questions/9793/test-token-is-different-from-generated-token-audie
maybe it makes it more logic for you, i'll try what I can with your post.

Comment: I changed the node source code, and added the audience at the place suggest on auth0 forum and now it works.
I like to thank you very much for your detailled instructions, as I can finally continue my project.